# Set a given binary flag

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a binary number and I want to apply a boolean value (true/false) to one of its flags

Supposing a binary value called myBinary 
I want to apply the boolean value X to the 4th flag (0x08) of myBinary

I know I can do it this way :

```
function applyBoolean(int myBinary, int mask, boolean X)
{
  if (x = true)
     myBinary = myBinary | mask

  else 
     myBinary  = myBinary & mask 

  return myBinary
}
```

**EDITED :**

So to change the 4th flag I can do so :

applyBoolean(100101, 001000, true) -----> returns : 101101

applyBoolean(100101, 001000, false) -----> returns : 100101

Now I wonder if it's possible to do it without if/else, using only bitwise operations.

Thanks

Comment: You say `apply the boolean value X to ... myBinary`, but you haven't demonstrated that in the `I know I can do it this way` sample. Do you actually want to treat `x` as the binary value `1000` (8)? I think we could use a little bit more explanation of what you're trying to accomplish. Please provide sample inputs to your `applyBoolean` function and your expected outputs.

Comment: It looks like by "apply" you're asking how to set a given bit to a given value, treating your number as a bit set. Is that correct? I think your provided code is close, but incorrect, for doing that. Also, what language are you using? You should edit your question to add more relevant tags and a clearer explanation of what you want.

Comment: That's correct Dan, sorry if my question was not clear.  I've just edited with an example using the method applyBoolean

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming `mask == 0x8` if `X == true` and `mask == ~0x8` if `X == false`, otherwise your statement wouldn't match your code.)

In order to use "only bitwise operations", you would have to convert that boolean into a number.
Since you didn't specify a programming language, I assume you are looking for a general/conceptual answer.
However, whether this is possible or not depends on the features of your programming language, namely on the ability to treat booleans as numbers.

For example, in JavaScript this can be done like

```
function applyBoolean(myBinary, X)
{
    return (myBinary & ~0x8) ^ (X << 3);
}
```

The logic behind this is relatively simple:

- Set `0x8` bit to `0` (by bitwise AND with the bitwise inverse of `0x8`).
- Shift `X` 3 bits to the left, implicitly converting it to a number.
- XOR `myBinary` with that value, resulting in bit `0x8` being `0` for `X == false` and `1` for `X == true`.

In PHP, it is practically the same:

```
function applyBoolean($myBinary, $X)
{
    return ($myBinary & ~0x8) ^ ($X << 3);
}
```

In Java, this cannot be done at all using only bitwise operators, as `boolean` cannot be cast to a number. You'd have to use `if`, the ternary operator or a function.

In some languages, such as Assembly and C prior to C99, this could be considered inapplicable, as those languages lack a (true) boolean type.
If `0` and `1` are considered booleans however, the solution is as trivial as rewriting the above snippet in those languages.

And last (and probably least too), some languages, such as Brainfuck, simply lack boolean operators, rendering this task impossible.